# Highcharts - draw path on chart with datetime axis

Tags: highcharts

I need to draw an arbitrary path on a chart that has a datetime axis:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
}
```

I'm trying to use `chart.renderer.path('M', x, y)`. I can easily determine the `y` value, but how do I specify the `x`?

Here is a simple example (based on a Highcharts' fiddle, copied to http://jsfiddle.net/ykcff0sL/3/). If you look at the last lines of the code, I want to add a line on the chart:

```
// add line from January to April
chart.renderer.path(
    'M', new Date(2014, 0, 1), 0.8,
    'L', new Date(2014, 3, 1), 0.9)
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add()
```

This is not working. I've also tried using `toPixels` to no avail.

```
   'M', chart.xAxis(0).toPixels(new Date(2014, 0, 1)), 0.8,
   'L', chart.xAxis(0).toPixels(new Date(2014, 3, 1)), 0.9)
```

Can you fix the jsfiddle example to work, or tell me how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Renderer.path` requires an array of coordinates.
`chart.xAxis` is also an array of axes, not a function.

To determine x and y of a specific coordinate, use `xAxis/yAxis.toPixels()`

```
      var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
  var yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

  chart.renderer.path([
      'M', xAxis.toPixels(new Date(2014, 0, 1)), yAxis.toPixels(0.8),
      'L', xAxis.toPixels(new Date(2014, 3, 1)), yAxis.toPixels(0.9)
    ])
    .attr({
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add()
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ykcff0sL/4/

Comment: Great. (The `xAxis(0)` was an error in preparing the sample.)